Django admin pannel redirect to /accounts/login/?next=/admin/
Whenever I open my django admin pannel it redirects to the following URL
/accounts/login/?next=/admin/
I'm using DRF and all my DRF APIs running properly but my admin pannel is not opening every time it is redirecting to above URL.
But I didn't setup any above URL in my project setup.

Please edit your question and include whether your settings.py contains a LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL value, and the contents of your urls.py

Are you using Django's built-in auth? The pattern makes me think of this helper function. You should double check your settings.py file for the LOGIN_URL as well.

I'm using DRF JWT authentication and checked my setting.py file there is no any LOGIN_URL path set

Do you have a user model or any auth model of any kind? And when you say, 'Whenever I open my django admin pannel it redirects to the following URL', how are you trying to open the admin panel?

I'm using django auth user. when I will add http://localhost:8000/admin then it is redirecting to this accounts/login url

are you able to share a link to a repo so we can try to recreate the issue? Something about your configuration must be off.
